# Explanation needed for this pre-processor directive C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I tried to solve this problem in some test, but later when i ran it at home, it gave unexpected answer.
I am not able to understand this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
int main()
{
int i, j, temp;
i=5;
j=10;
temp=0;
if( i > j) //evaluates to false
swap( i, j );
printf( "%d %d %d", i, j, temp); //expected output: 5 10 0
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Output i am getting is: 10 0 0

Please someone explain how is it working.

Comment: Just a suggestion, Avoid `conio`, `getch` etc.

Comment: Ok, i won't be using them often.

Comment: Another suggestion is to never write macros like that, they are unsafe in many ways. Instead, use a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Code below

```
if( i > j) //evaluates to false
swap( i, j );
```

Becomes

```
if( i > j) //evaluates to false
temp=i; i=j; j=temp;
```

which is equivalent to

```
if( i > j) //evaluates to false
{temp=i;} i=j; j=temp;
```

If condition is false, there would be unexpected results as below

```
i=5;
j=10;
temp=0;
i=j;  /* i becomes 10 */
j=temp; /* j becomes 0 */
```

**Learnings**

1. Try to put blocks (if, else, for, do, while) inside `{}`
2. Avoid macros, prefer functions
3. If you must use macros, use safe macros, for ex:

`#define swap(a,b) do { temp=a; a=b; b=temp; } while(0)`

<sup>Note that there is [no terminating semicolon after while(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros?lq=1)</sup>

Comment: Thanx.. I got the missing link. :)

Comment: Now that you see an example of macro horror, work out what this expands to: `swap(a[i++], b[i++])`

Comment: @Jerry101 That line would yield undefined behavior no matter if swap is a macro or a function...

Comment: @Lundin Possibly he meant `swap(a[i++], b[j++])` and ended up in a typo

Comment: @Lundin is right about undefined behavior. (Side point: In Java the order of evaluation is well defined.) Using Mohit's variation, a template function with T& parameters would do a useful swap, while a macro is bad.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the macro, you get:

```
if (i > j)
   temp = i;
i = j;
j = temp;
```

This is why seasoned c-programmers wrap macro bodies in `do{...}while(0)`.

```
#define swap(a, b) do{temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}while(0)
```

Comment: More brownie points if you explain the outer loop (forces semicolon termination) and then bring temp into the local scope.

Comment: More seasoned programmers use inline functions instead of macros

Comment: seasoned programmers also don't omit the braces after an `if`