# Preprocessor directives in C : macros using __LINE__

Tags: c, header, preprocessor-directive

I find it difficult to understand the working of a macro defined with the help of preprocessor directives.

The macro,

```
TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN()
```

is defined with the help of two preprocessor directives refereed from two header files. Firstly, I wish to state the declaration of the said macro.

```
#define TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN() st( TRXEM_PORT_OUT &= ~TRXEM_SPI_SC_N_PIN; NOP();)
```

As the declaration of macro `st ()` is missing here, I found it defined in a different header file and ti is shown below.

```
#define st(x) do { x } while (__LINE__ == -1)
```

Now after combining two macros, the true definition of macro `TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN()` must be,

```
#define TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN() do {

( TRXEM_PORT_OUT &= ~TRXEM_SPI_SC_N_PIN; NOP(); )

} while (__LINE__ == -1)
```

This code is written to work inside a microcontroler where `TRXEM_PORT_OUT`, `RXEM_SPI_SC_N_PIN` are memory mapped registers and `NOP` initiates an instruction cycle that does nothing.

As per my understanding, `__LINE__` means the line of code in the c file where `__LINE__` lies. That line can never be equal to `-1`. i.e. this loopmust always be running **only once** provided the `__LINE__` can never be placed in `-1` place in a `.c` file. Simply put, `-1` can never be the  value of `__LINE__`.

Therefore, I believe a `do while()` loop here is unnecessary and the same output could have been achieved by simply without using any looping.

I do not understand the functioning of this macro. I would so much appreciate if someone could elaborate on it.

Comment: These are (function type) macros or macros with arguments not functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [do { ... } while (0) — what is it good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Comment: @mohitJain this question is completely different to what you have marked it duplicated with.

Comment: OK, read my answer and then check the question that is marked duplicate :) and then you can leave comment or say thank you if your question is solved :)

Comment: Presumably `st()` means "statementify", i.e. it makes its argument into a proper C statement. The use of `__LINE == -1` instead of just `0` is just a sign of someone being seriously confused. It's a bug and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding,  means the line of code in the c file
>   where `__LINE__` lies. That line can never be equal to -1. i.e. this
>   loopmust always be running only once provided the `__LINE__` can never
>   be placed in -1 place in a .c file. Simply put, -1 can never be the
>   return value to a `__LINE__`.

Your understanding is exactly correct here. It is there to make sure the code runs exactly once.

Think of following scenario:

```
#define BAZ foo();bar();
```

Now if you do

```
if(some_cond) BAZ;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if(some_cond) foo();
bar();
```

Which is most possibly not something you want. So you change it to:

```
#define BAZ {foo();bar();}
```

This works fine if written as `if(some_cond) foo() else wow();` but would fail compilation if written as `if(some_cond) foo(); else wow();`

So you define `BAZ` as

```
/* No semicolon at end */
#define BAZ do {foo();bar();} while(condition_which_is_always_false)
```

And you can now write the natural code with intuitive semicolon at end.

In your case, `condition_which_is_always_false` is `__LINE__ == -1`

Comment: Thanks you @mohitJain. Truly appreciate your effort. When I first studied your reference it didn't make much sense to me. Now it actually does make much sense and thank you so much for your patience. Truly appreciate it.

Comment: I am glad if it helps. You may also find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985515/is-warning-c4127-conditional-expression-is-constant-ever-helpful) interesting.